# Safari automatic "display: none !important" won't load image

Tags: html, css, image, safari

I'm currently building a website and everything's loading in just fine except for a few pictures (other pictures load without any problem). I've seen that the images get automatically get the CSS attribute "display: none !important".

This problem only happens in Safari (Chrome loads the pictures just fine!)

HTML:

```
    <div id="socialLinks">
        <img src="img/social/white/linkedin.png" alt="linkedin">
        <img src="img/social/white/facebook.png" alt="facebook">
        <img src="img/social/white/google.png" alt="google">
        <img src="img/social/white/email.png" alt="email">
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#socialLinks
{
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: -4%;
    float: right;
    top: 7%;
    left: 88vw;
}
```

I've tried everything I could think of. Safari does find the image path and sometimes does show the alt attr.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are they getting the `display:none!important;` from? Some browsers don't load images that have `display:none` when the page is initialized

Comment: They are adding this themselves. Now I did find out that it has something to do with my AdBlocker. It blocks the images from being loaded in.

This does fix the problem partially. When I disable my AdBlocker the images do show, however they need to show when I have my AdBlocker active (since it's not an advertisement)

Comment: This is exactly what the adblocker is *for*.

Answer (score 10):

AdBlockers work in a variety of ways, and often will attempt to hide social links/ calls to action.

try these steps in order, and together, seeing what you have to do to get the images past your adBlock:

1. Change the ID of `#socialLinks` to something different
2. Change the `src` of the images to not be served from a folder called `social`
3. Change the name of each of the images to something different, ie: `icon1.png`
4. Change the alt text to something without the name of the social media site
5. Give up. Its the `href` of your links that is causing them to be blocked

Font Awesome have run into this issue themselves:

> "Apparently, Adblock Plus can remove Font Awesome brand icons with their "Remove Social Media Buttons" setting. We will not use hacks to force them to display. Please report an issue with Adblock Plus if you believe this to be an error. To work around this, you'll need to modify the social icon class names."
>   *from [http://fontawesome.io/icons/](http://fontawesome.io/icons/_)*

Comment: AdBlock Plus also blocks images served from "ad" or "ads" folder. Sounds like obvious? It also alters the source code of such pages opened in a web HTML editor such as TinyMCE and you end up scratching your head how that strange class got into the code.

Comment: This worked for me! Thank you. For example, don't name a class "linkedin-logo" or name of the image as "linkedin-logo.png" etc. They get caught by adblockers.

Answer (score 1):

For me, adblock blocked my image cause name of image.
My image name's:

> something-relate-to-image-728x90

They blocked 728x90 because it's recognize the size of ads in name.

Answer (score 0):

The issue doesn't have anything to do with the browser. I faced the same issue with Google Chrome.
It is because of the ad-blocker extension installed on your browser. You can verify it by checking the sources section on your console, you can see a file from ad-blocker.org
So what this ad-blockers does is, it checks your page for certain keywords like "ad", "social", and also filters based on popular social media sites like, "facebook", "twitter", "linkedin", etc and adds `display: none !important` for all these elements.
It checks across all selectors which includes `id`, `class`, `name` and `alt` properties.

The solution to this issue would be to rename your classes, id and other properties to something that the ad-blocker doesn't pickup. For example: rename your class `.social-icon` to just `.icons`, rename your image name from `facebook.svg` to `fb.svg`, change your alt from `alt="twitter"` to `alt="tweet icon"`.
PFB the set of selectors that the ad-blocker added to my page to just get an idea of how ad-blockers hide the elements.
[image]